What is the error in reasoning to conclude that $f(x) \equiv f(0) \ (\mathrm{mod}\ x)$?
$\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)}$
I was playing around with modulos and I noticed that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{k}{\left( n+a_i \right) } \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{k}{a_i} \Mod{n}
$$
This can be seen quite easily by expanding the left-hand side, which will contain many terms multiplied by some power of $n$, plus some constant which is equal to the product of all $a_i$-s. Taking$\mod{n}$ of that will cause all the terms multiplied by powers of $n$ to become $0$, resulting in just the latter part$\mod{n}$.
If both sides are multiplied by some constant, $C$, then the left hand side would be a polynomial of $n$. So, for any polynomial, the adjusted formula would hold true:
$$
p(n) = C\prod_{i=1}^k \left( n - a_i \right) \equiv C\prod_{i=1}^k -a_i \Mod{n}
$$
Where each $a_i$ is a root of the polynomial.
However, any arbitrary continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $(-\infty, \infty)$ can be written using a Maclaurin series as an infinite sum of polynomials. So taking it modulo $x$ will perform the above formula for each term in the series:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f^{(i)}\left( x_0 \right )\left (x - x_0 \right)^i
\\
f(x) \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f^{(i)}\left(x_0\right)\left(-x_0\right)^i \Mod{x}
$$
However, the Maclaurin series converges to the same function no matter what $x_0$ is used, so let $x_0 = 0$. Then, for $i > 0$, the terms become $0$, so only the initial $i=0$ term contributes:
$$
f(x) \equiv f(0) \Mod{x}
$$
So that is what I get. However, it is pretty easy to show that this isn't correct. For example, let $f(x) = 2^x$, $f(0) = 1$. If $x = 3$, then $f(x) = 8 \not\equiv 1 \Mod{3}$. And this is for integers, which I'm sure modulo properties work for.
Additionally, if $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, $f(0) = 1$ and let $x = \frac{1}{2}$; $f(x) = \frac{5}{4} \not\equiv 1 \Mod{\frac{1}{2}}$. This uses fractions, which I don't know if you can do modulo with them. I'm pretty sure you can, but perhaps not all the properties apply for them?
What is wrong with my reasoning here? I've gone over it a few times and can't find what is wrong about it.

You forgot to divide by $i!$. You also forgot that the derivatives at $x_0$ don't have to be integers, but this is less important, because the result can fail even if these derivatives are all integers.
Being explicit, there is no guarantee that for integers $i \geq j>0$, $\frac{1}{i!} f^{(i)}(x_0) {i \choose j} x^{j-1} (-x_0)^{i-j}$ is an integer just because $x$ and $x_0$ are. This is what would be required to run your argument in the exact way you did it. Indeed if $f$ is actually analytic* but not a polynomial, then eventually this will not happen, because all but finitely many terms will be in the interval $(-1,1)$ (by analyticity) and there are infinitely many nonzero terms (by not being a polynomial).
* Your continuity assumption is nowhere near strong enough for this by the way.

I cannot believe I forgot that division! My bad. But would it still work even if it wasn't an integer? For example, you could think that 3/2 = 1/2 (mod 1).

@Apuji You could do all these modulo operations, but you wouldn't get a whole bunch of zeros like you expected. For example, look at the Maclaurin series of $e^1$; the first two terms are $0$ mod 1 but then the rest are just themselves mod 1. So instead of some super simple picture you get $\sum_{n=2}^\infty 1/n!$ for the remainder mod 1.
